# Sum of every row, column and diagonal is equal to 0. Is it possible that none of the numbers is eqaul to zero?

Tags: combinatorics

A square with 2015 rows and 2015 columns is filled with integers. The sum of every row is equal to zero, the sum of every column is equal to zero, and sum of the two main diagonals is equal to zero. Is it possible that none of the numbers in square is equal to zero? How can I prove it?

Comment: By "diagonal" do you mean only the two main diagonals? And do you mean a square with 2015 columns and 2015 rows?

Comment: Yes, only two main diagonals. It is square with 2015 columns and 2015 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael beat me to writing a similar general idea, but here are the specifics. Consider this $5\times 5$ square:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  17& 17& -8&-18& -8\\
   7&-23&  2& 12&  2\\
  -8&  2&  2&  2&  2\\
  -8&  2&  2&  2&  2\\
  -8&  2&  2&  2&  2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Each row, column, and main diagonal sums to zero. Fill up the $2015\times 2015$ square with this, $403$ times across and $403$ times down, and the entire square will also have those properties. This is true since each row, column, and main diagonal of the large square will be made of $403$ copies of rows, columns, and main diagonals of this $5\times 5$ square.

I found this square by solving the $12$ linear equations in $25$ variables that come from the condition. The $2$'s are the basis of the solution, while the others are determined from the $2$'s. The $2$'s could be changed to get other suitable squares.

Comment: What is the dimension of the vector space consisting only this kind of matrices?

Comment: @HarryPotter: This particular matrix has rank 2, so the overall $2015\times 2015$ matrix would also have rank 2. But as I wrote in my answer, there are many other matrices that satisify the OP's conditions: I just got a simple matrix by using as many $2$'s as possible. Using other values rather than those $2$'s may result in a different rank. The condition that the rows sum to zero, for example, which is a linear combination, means that the rank could be at most 4.

Comment: Sorry if my question didn't make sense, but here is more proper one- Suppose $V$ is a vector space of matrices whose row sum, column sum and sum of the two diagonals are zero. What is the dimension of $V$?

Comment: @HarryPotter: If you mean the subspace of the $n\times n$ matrices, there are $n^2$ possible elements for each matrix. Specifying the sum of rows is $n$ conditions, the sum of columns is another $n$ conditions, and the sum of the two diagonals is another $2$ conditions. That reduces the dimension by $2n+2$ if those conditions are independent, by fewer if they are not. The conditions are not independent, so the number of dimensions is greater than $n^2-2n-2$. Can you finish the job and find the final number of dimensions? Try some smaller values of $n$ to see the pattern.

Comment: Ok let me try. I'll ask you if unable to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a $5\times5$ matrix of this form:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}a&b&c&b&a\\b&d&e&d&b\\c&e&f&e&c\\b&d&e&d&b\\a&b&c&b&a\end{array}\right]$$
that obeys your rules.  Your have four equations in six variables.
Now fill your $2015\times2015$  square with these smaller squares.